# What does "shared" mean in ~/.cabal/config?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I guess that "shared" will make `cabal install` faster, right ?  The default value of shared is False. Should we use True or False for shared ?

thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means "also build dynamically-linked (aka shared) versions of libraries that are installed with `cabal install`".

```
$ cabal help install | grep shared
    --enable-shared                Enable Shared library
    --disable-shared               Disable Shared library
```

By default, only statically-linked versions are built. So it won't make `cabal install libfoo` faster - on the contrary, building `libfoo` will take more time.

Comment: compiling `libfoo` will take more time, but linking will likely be faster if all the dependencies are dynamically linked.  As to which effect is larger, it depends.  But I've frequently seen ld start swapping, so I'm tempted to think shared builds would be faster on net (at least on this box, where ghc doesn't completely support shared libs).

Comment: @JohnL `shared: True` won't enable dynamic linking for executables, there's `executable-dynamic` for that.

Comment: yes, but the usual use case for enabling shared libraries is so you can use them in executables.  And linking those executables should be faster.