# Linked Cabal sandboxes - shared libraries not found from `cabal repl`

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, cabal, cabal-install

I've got two packages that I'm developing, `A` and `B`. Package `B` depends on `A`.

`A` was developed in it's own sandbox, and a similar story goes for `B`:

```
A> cabal sandbox init
A> cabal install --enable-shared

B> cabal sandbox init
B> cabal sandbox add-source ../A/
B> cabal install
```

also note that `shared: True` is in my `~/.cabal/config`.

Everything looks good here, they both install just fine. However, while working on `B`, if I issue `cabal repl`, cabal-install tells me that it can't load the `libAsomething.so/.dll` file. What went wrong here?

Here is the exact error:

```
...
Loading package mtl-0.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package A-0.0.0 ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /home/athan/dev/A/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3/A-0.0.0/libHSA-0.0.0-ghc7.8.3.so (/home/athan/dev/foo/B/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.8.3/A-0.0.0/libHSA-0.0.0-ghc7.8.3.so: undefined symbol: AsomethingCrazyInAmodule_closure)
```

Edit:

I'm using GHC 7.8.3 and cabal-install 1.20.0.3.

Comment: what is 'share: True' supposed to do ?

Comment: @mb14 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188387/what-does-shared-mean-in-cabal-config

Comment: Are you that `--enable-shared` will set `shared`. It might be the case but the link you refer doesn't say anything about `shared` in `~/.cabal/config`. Anyway this `--enable-share` doesn't share library between cabal sandbox but uses shared library vs static one, which is totally different.

Comment: You don't need to create a sandbox for A to be able to add it into a sandbox for B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does using just one sandbox work for you?

```
(unpack A into src/A)
(unpack B into src/B)
cd src/B
cabal sandbox init
cabal add-source ../src/A
cabal install                -- builds both A and B
```

Now there is only one sandbox (located in src/B).

Comment: `add-source` doesn't share the sandbox. `cabal sandbox init --sandbox ../src/A` does.